Error when using tmap: Error in if (hover != "" && !hover %in% smeta$vars) rlang::arg_match0(hover, : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
I am trying to make a map using the tmap package in R, because I have a continous raster for which I think using Jenks Nature Breaks would be usful for visualisation. Thus far this is what I have:
tm_shape(r) + tm_borders() + tm_scale_intervals(style = "jenks")

However when I try to run this code, I get:
Error in if (hover != "" && !hover %in% smeta$vars) rlang::arg_match0(hover,  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I have tried with other rasters, and simplifying it so it merely reads
tm_shape(r)

And I get the same error. My raster is a RasterLayer object, but in theory tmap should still permit me to use a raster object not created using the sf or stars packages. Am I failing to put an argument, or do I have to convert the RasterLayer into a raster type which would be more familiar to sf or stars?

What version of tmap are you using? The one currently on CRAN doesn't have a tm_scale_intervals function so I'm guessing you've got a development version from github?

Using version 3.99.9001 from github, I get your error, but you can't use tm_borders with a raster.
> r = raster(matrix(runif(100),10,10))
> tm_shape(r) + tm_borders() + tm_scale_intervals(style = "jenks")
Error in if (hover != "" && !hover %in% smeta$vars) rlang::arg_match0(hover,  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Instead you use tm_raster and add an argument for the colour scale:
tm_shape(r) + tm_raster(col.scale = tm_scale_intervals(style="jenks"))


